# Issue registering form control with interpolated name

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code attempting to apply some validation styling using `ng-class`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
    <select name="itemName{{$index}}" ng-model="item.name" ng-options="o for o in nameOptions"
      ng-class="{ 'custom-error': myForm.itemName{{$index}}.$invalid && !myForm.itemName{{$index}}.$pristine }"
      required>
        <option value="">SELECT</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My class is not being applied and I cannot see why. The generated html looks as expected with the name matching its counterpart in the `ng-class` expression.

When I replicate this outside of an `ng-repeat` (not using `$index` for naming) it works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the control's name (the one with which it is registered on its parent form) is retrieved during the `ngModelController`'s instantiation, which **[according to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-controller-)** takes place before the pre-linking phase* (so no interpolation yet).

If you inspect the `myForm`'s properties, you will find out it indeed has a property with key "itemName{{$index}}".

---

***UPDATE**

The docs on **[`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)** are a great resource for understanding what makes a directive tick and what is going on "behind the scenes".

In plain words there are two main phases: the **compiling** phase and the **linking** phase.

During the **compiling** phase, the template is being prepared (e.g. it might need to be cloned etc) and is made Angular-aware (e.g. the directives are compiled and the expressions are parsed and ready to be evaluated), but it is not bound to a scope yet (thus there is nothing to evaluate against).

> The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM. Since most directives do not do template transformation, it is not used often. Examples that require compile functions are directives that transform template DOM, such as ngRepeat, or load the contents asynchronously, such as ngView.

The **linking** phase is further devided into two sub-phases: ***pre-linking*** and ***post-linking***.

During this phase, a scope comes into play and the interpolated expressions (such as your `name` attribute) can be evaluated against the scope's properties/functions.

> The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned. This is where most of the directive logic will be put.
>
> **Pre-linking function**
>   Executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate the correct elements for linking.
>
> **Post-linking function**
>   Executed after the child elements are linked. It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function.

---

So, in your case, here is what happens:

1. The `ngModel` directive, which is responsible for registering the element on its parent form's `FormController`, calls `formCtrl.$addControl(modelCtrl);` in its post-linking function.
2. The `FormController` uses the specified controller's `$name` property to register the control:
   `form[control.$name] = control;`
3. In the case of `ngModel` the controller is an instance of `ngModelCntroller` and it's `$name` property is defined like this:
   `function(..., $attr, ...) { ... this.$name = $attr.name;`
4. Since the controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase, `$attr.name` is bound to the un-interpolated string (i.e. "itemName{{$index}}").

---

**UPDATE 2**

Now that we know what the issue is, it only seems logical to go ahead and fix it :)

Here is an implementation that would solve the issue:

1. Do not set a `name` attribute, so nothing is registered with `myForm` (we will take care of the registering manually).
2. Create a directive that registers the control with the parent form's `FormController` only after evaluating the expression against the element's scope (let's call the directive `later-name`).
3. Since the controls are registered to the `FormController` through their `ngModelController`, our directive must get access to those two controllers (through its **[`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-require-)** property).
4. Before registering the control, our directive will update the `ngModelController`'s `$name` property (and set a name on the element).
5. Our directive must also take care of removing the control "manually" (since we are adding it manually).

Easy as pie:

```
<select later-name="itemName{{$index}}"                  <!-- (1) -->

app.directive('laterName', function () {                   // (2)
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['?ngModel', '^?form'],                   // (3)
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
            attrs.$set('name', attrs.laterName);

            var modelCtrl = ctrls[0];                      // (3)
            var formCtrl  = ctrls[1];                      // (3)
            if (modelCtrl && formCtrl) {
                modelCtrl.$name = attrs.name;              // (4)
                formCtrl.$addControl(modelCtrl);           // (2)
                scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    formCtrl.$removeControl(modelCtrl);    // (5)
                });
            }            
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/5rjp2/)**.

Comment: I see that it has the itemName{{$index}} property. Can you expand on that first part a bit?

Comment: What do you want me to expand on ? What is the pre-linking phase ? Or how/when are the controls registered with their parent form's `FormCotroller` ?

Comment: the pre-linking phase

Comment: @aw04: There you go ! Expanded :)

Comment: Well expanded I must say :) Thank you for taking the time to help me understand, and your directive works brilliantly!