# dynamically naming input controls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive

I have a input element which I am trying to name dynamically, but I had no luck so far using angular js.

neither

```
<input type="text" name="resource.Name" ng-model="resource.Value" ng-required="resource.IsRequired">
```

nor

```
<input type="text" name="{{resource.Name}}" ng-model="resource.Value" ng-required="resource.IsRequired">
```

works for me. When I try to access name attribute it always comes back as resource.Name instead of the value it contains. The main reason I am trying to name this input control is validation, if user does not enter text in the field, I would like to tell them which textbox is required. If there is any angular directive I can use for that purpose I am ready to use them as well.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

My validation function is as follows:

```
 window.resourcesValidation = function ($scope, $rootScope, $alert) {
        var subscriptions = $scope.scopeData.Subscriptions;
        var isValidated = true;

        if ($scope.resourceDataForm && $scope.resourceDataForm.$error && $scope.resourceDataForm.$error.required) {
            var missingFields = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.resourceDataForm.$error.required, function (value, key) {
                isValidated = false;
                missingFields.push("-" + value.$name);
            });

            $alert.error("Please fill in the all required fields.\r\n" + missingFields.join("\r\n"));
        }

        if (isValidated)
            $scope.saveChanges(subscriptions);

        return isValidated;
    };
```

Comment: What does $scope.resourceDataForm look like?  Any chance you can make a demo in plunker or something?

Comment: Why are you putting resourcesValidation in a global function and not inside of a module's controller?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the resourcesValidation function and look at `$scope.resourceDataForm`.  Is `$scope.resourceDataForm.$error.required` an array?  Do its items have a `$name` property?  Can you post what the entire object looks like?

Comment: Yes Jerrad that's an array. first element has a $name property, which has the following value: {{subscriptionResource.Name}}, I think angularjs's ng-required validation uses name of the control before it is binded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting another answer on a very similar issue:

> This happens because the control's name (the one with which it is registered on its parent form) is retrieved during the `ngModelController`'s instantiation, which **[according to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-controller-)** takes place before the pre-linking phase* (so no interpolation yet).

---

In other words, validation relies on `forms.$error` object, which is bound to the controls that are registered with that form.
A control's `ngModelController` is responsible for registering a control with its parent form and it is instantiated at the pre-linking phase (when the name-expression is not interpolated yet).

This can be solved by a custom directive that manually registers the control with its parent form, but only after it's actual name is determined (after insterpolating the name-expression).

---

You can find the whole answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616578/issue-registering-form-control-with-interpolated-name#answer-23617401)**.
Look for the **UPDATE 2** section for a working solution.

(This is the link to the **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/5rjp2/)**.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be my problem. I will ive it a try and let you knowç

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" ng-attr-name="{{resource.Name}}" ng-model="resource.Value" ng-required="resource.IsRequired">
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the ngAttr prefix (denormalized as ng-attr-) then during the binding will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute.

Although `name="{{resource.Name}}"` should work in this case as well.

### Update

I found a solution here: [Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs)

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WISaf7lsHgpm9NQ7mK7U?p=preview) that I made.

Sounds like this issue may be fixed in Angular 1.3.

Comment: It works but I still can't access the name of the control properly in my validation function.

Comment: That's a separate issue.  Can we see your validation function?

Comment: I just posted it in the original question.

Comment: Maybe you could add some informations why you changed in the original code in this way so that future readers can understand that and fix their problem which is similar to this.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality due to its brevity. Would you mind adding some text to explain how this code answers the question?

Comment: guys relax, I am trying to come up with an easy way of putting this into plnkr, it is a part of a huge single page application, I don't know how it is possible to post the entire thing here.

Comment: I tried to isolate my problem and ask the question, but it seems that my problem goes deeper than this.

Comment: The original question just asked how to bind the name property.  My answer provided a solution to that.  They didn't add the bit about the validation function until after I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the rest of your code? (HTML, relevant controllers, etc.)

Sometimes the issue can center around asynchrony. For example, the HTML might be compiled by Angular's compiler before your `$scope.resource` object gets its data (perhaps, with an AJAX call).

Two-way data binding sometimes doesn't always work how you would expect. Therefore, after "putting" your data into `$scope.resource` with whatever function, you might need to call `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: I think my problem is in my validation function, I posted it right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ng-model="resource.model" name="{{resource.name}}" ng-required="{{resource.required}}"/>
```

seems to be working for me. Please see this  [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYxkOvNzKVc7OMiecs51?p=preview) .

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the answer that satisfied some or all of these needs.  This is what I came up with.

There may be a better way, so please share your thoughts.
I am using Angularjs 1.3.0-beta.8

I have a form with multi-nested directives that all contain input(s), select(s), etc...
These elements are all enclosed in ng-repeats, and dynamic string values.

This is how to use the directive:

```
<form name="myFormName">
  <nested directives of many levels>
    ex: <input ng-repeat=(index, variable) in variables" type="text"
               my-name="{{ variable.name + '/' + 'myFormName' }}"
               ng-model="variable.name" required />
    ex: <select ng-model="variable.name" ng-options="label in label in {{ variable.options }}"
                my-name="{{ variable.name + '/' + 'myFormName' }}"
        </select>
</form>
```

Note: you can add and index to the string concatenation if you need to serialize perhaps a table of inputs; which is what I did. However, dynamic name inputs means you may not know the name of the form input, so how would you call $scope.formName.??????.  You could iterate of the $scope.formName object to get keys that match a certain value. That means string concatenation like this:

```
my-name="{{ dynamicString + hello + '/' + 'myFormName' }}"
```

Then in $scope.myFormName you would find any form input name by just iterating over the object and gathering any keys that included 'hello'.

```
app.directive('rsName', function(){

  var rsNameError = "rsName directive error: "

  return {
    restrict:'A', // Declares an Attributes Directive.
    require: 'ngModel', // ngModelController.

    link: function( scope, elem, attrs, ngModel ){
      if( !ngModel ){ return } // no ngModel exists for this element

      // check rsName input for proper formatting ex. something/something
      checkInputFormat(attrs);

      var inputName = attrs.rsName.match('^\\w+').pop(); // match upto '/'
      assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel);

      var formName = attrs.rsName.match('\\w+$').pop(); // match after '/'
      findForm(formName, ngModel, scope);
    } // end link
  } // end return

  function checkInputFormat(attrs){
    if( !/\w\/\w/.test(attrs.rsName )){
      throw rsNameError + "Formatting should be \"inputName/formName\" but is " + attrs.rsName
    }
  }

  function assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel){
    ngModel.$name = inputName
  }

  function addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    scope[formName][ngModel.$name] = ngModel; return
  }

  function findForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    if( !scope ){ // ran out of scope before finding scope[formName]
      throw rsNameError + "<Form> element named " + formName + " could not be found."
    }

    if( formName in scope){ // found scope[formName]
      addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope)
      return
    }
    findForm(formName, ngModel, scope.$parent) // recursively search through $parent scopes
  }
});
```

This should handle many situations where you just don't know where the form will be.  Or perhaps you have nested forms, but for some reason you want to attach this input name to two forms up?  Well, just pass in the form name you want to attach the input name to.

What I wanted, was a way to assign dynamic values to inputs that I will never know, and then just call $scope.myFormName.$valid.

This may be an overkill, and a better solution exists in 1.3+.  I couldn't find it in the time I had.  This works for me now.

Good luck!  Hope this helps someone!!!!