# AngularJs: using $setValidity on array input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm working with AngularJs 1.2. I have a problem with $setValidity.

I have a form input with ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in addition_page">
    <input ng-model="addition_page[key].name" name="pagename[{{key}}]" not-duplicated="1"> 
</div>
```

Now I need to use $setValidity on some specify input, but I failed

```
scope["finish_form"]["pagename[0]"].$setValidity('not-duplicated', false);
```

I tried to log:

```
console.log(scope["finish_form"]["pagename[0]"]) => return undefined
console.log(scope["finish_form"]["pagename[{{key}}]"]) => return last input
```

I inspected element on browser, pagename[0] is existed.

I need help, plz.

Thank you all.

Update:

```
.directive('notDuplicated', [function() {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                    var val_id = attr.notDuplicated;

                    var setValidity = function(value) {
                        if (value === "") return true;
                        var same_now = [];
                        var same_past = [];
                        angular.element("[not-duplicated=" + val_id + "]").each(function(k, v) {
                            if (angular.element(v).val() === value) {
                                same_now.push(k);
                            }
                            if (ngModel.$modelValue !== "" && angular.element(v).val() === ngModel.$modelValue) {
                                same_past.push(k);
                            }
                        })

                        // mark old input is valid
                        if (same_past.length === 1) {
                            scope["finish_form"]["pagename[" + same_past[0] + "]"].$setValidity('not-duplicated', true);
                        }

                        // mark new inputs is invalid
                        if (same_now.length > 1) {
                            same_now.each(function(k) {
                                scope["finish_form"]["pagename[" + k + "]"].$setValidity('not-duplicated', false);
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;

                    }

                    //For DOM -> model validation
                    ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                        var valid = setValidity(value);
                        return valid ? value : undefined;
                    });

                    //For model -> DOM validation
                    ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                        setValidity(value);
                        return value;
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: where are you doing this: "scope["finish_form"]["pagename[0]"].$setValidity('not-duplicated', false);"? Are you doing that inside the link function of a custom validation directive?

Comment: Are you doing that inside the link function of a custom validation directive? => Yes.Inside ngModel.$parsers.unshift and ngModel.$formatters.unshift

Comment: mmmmmmm, could you please share the rest of that code?

Comment: I appended my directive. Take a look at that. Thank you.

Comment: For ngModelController name interpolation `{{}}` do not work. Look at ng-form directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the control's name (the one with which it is registered on its parent form) is retrieved during the `ngModelController`'s instantiation, which **[according to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)** takes place before the pre-linking phase* (so no interpolation yet).

If you inspect the `myForm`'s properties, you will find out that all the inputs are registered as "pagename[{{key}}]".

---

Take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616578/issue-registering-form-control-with-interpolated-name#answer-23617401)** for a more detailed explanation and a possible solution (using an extra directive).

Comment: @LêTrầnTiếnTrung: Glad to know :) Feel free to also upvote the other answer to let other people know it helped you with your problem.